# New position of layout during animation is resetting after ui interaction

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, position

I am working in android 2.3 and I have an issue which is a bit of a pain.

I have 2 layouts on top of each other in a `FrameLayout`. The top layout is moved partly off-screen during an animation, and the `.layout()` method is called in the animation end. This works great and the ui is moved correctly and the buttons of the toplayout is still clickable.
After the animation the second layout is visible as the toplayout is moved off-screen. This layout contains a list which is clickable and each cell has an `ImageView` which is updated when clicked. However my problem is, when the table cell is clicked and the `ImageView` is updated, the entire view is reset, ignorering the animation and new location of the toplayout. It just sets the toplayout back on top as the animation never happend.

I use an `TranslateAnimation` and the set fillafter is set to true as well.

Do you guys have any suggestions to what I might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is placing objects inside FrameLayout. As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5131992) you cannot place a view inside a FrameLayout by setting its location.

> It's true that with FrameLayout all children are pegged to the top
>   left of the screen, but you still have some control with setting their
>   padding. If you set different padding values to different children,
>   they will show up at different places in the FrameLayout.

Use padding instead to "move" the view off-screen.