# Android - Stack XML Layouts ontop of each other

Tags: java, android

If you look at Instagram, they have posts stacked on posts, with each post containing comments, picture, publisher's username, etc.

Looks like a XML layout is reused/repeated throughout a screen/view.

Is that what they are doing?
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FrameLayout & RelativeLayout let you stack Views above each other, the z index is by the order they are added in code or written in xml.
A layout is basically an extension of ViewGroup with rules, If you want to include another layout in a layout look into `<include>` and `<merge>` tags:
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: Now how could I have for example:
Layout 1
Include
Layout 1

programatically?

Comment: Any Layout can be inflated with View.inflate and  check this question about adding the new View to a FrameLayout for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8931551/348378

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using a `FrameLayout` and some `TextViews`. All the views' inside this `FrameLayout` will appear at the (0,0) coordinate but have an offset found in the dimension of the childs individual view's `android:layout_marginLeft/android:layout_marginStart` and `android:layout_marginTop` attributes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="11111111"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp" />


    <TextView
        android:text="2222222"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="3333333"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And what it looks like:

[image: And what it looks like]