# Programmatically Position Views in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want my TextView to appear below my ImageView in a RelativeLayout that is going into a GridView.  I've tried:

```
public override View  GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent);
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView tv;

        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.LayoutParameters = new GridView.LayoutParams(250, 250);
        imageView.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
        imageView.SetPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        imageView.SetImageResource(thumbIds[position]);
        imageView.Id = position;

        lp.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, position);
        lp.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterHorizontal);

        tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.Text = stringIds[position].ToString();
        tv.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Dip, 20);
        tv.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.WhiteSmoke);
        tv.LayoutParameters = lp;

        rl.AddView(imageView);
        rl.AddView(tv);

        return rl;
    }
```

But the TextView always shows up on top of the ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my content is not dynamic, I worked around the issue by simply editing my image in Paint and placing text below the image.  Then I made that the background for the ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/laying-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically).

When you call `rl.AddView(tv)`, you should include the LayoutParams `rl.AddView(tv, lp)`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  I'm not adding the same LayoutParameters for both views, I am only setting LayoutParameters (lp) on the TextView because that is the only one I care about position. I just want it under wherever the ImageView goes.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I read the question incorrectly. Updated my answer.

Comment: Tried it.  Doesn't seem to do anything differently from when I had tv.LayoutParameters = lp.  Weird thing is now that I have two different ImageViews and 2 TextViews, the 2nd set shows up properly with the ImageView on top and the TextView below it.  The first set still shows up with the two overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp) in order to assign the params to your view.

[How do you setLayoutParams() for an ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965662/how-do-you-setlayoutparams-for-an-imageview)