# how to use view.setX() method in android version less then 3.0

Tags: android

i want to implement drag and drop feature but the device version is 2.2.1 so application is not working i am use onTouch method and set coordinate using setx() and setY() but this method is not working on my device version please tell me the alternet way to implement this thanks in advance

Comment: you might wanna check layoutparams out. i think thats the way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965662/how-do-you-setlayoutparams-for-an-imageview

Comment: setX and setY are only supported above api 11.

Comment: similar type of question solved at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195768/android-use-of-view-setx-and-sety-in-api-8/12195999#12195999

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly Android Support Package doesn't contain new Drag-n-Drop from API 11 (Android 3.0) probably because it would need platform-side changes.

Basically you can find examples in Android 2.1 source code for [Launcher](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_launcher). But it's a bit complicated. Checkout [this implementation](https://sites.google.com/site/ericbharlow/sample-code/DragNDrop.zip) of custom `ListView` component with drag-n-drop. It helped me a lot when I had the same task.

Comment: thanks i have completed this for API below 11 we can use Layout param its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Use this jar file to use functions of all versions up to version 4.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidsupportv4jar.htm

Comment: hi nikhil.I imported the jar.but setX method is still not available.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not support this method in version < 3.0 but if you want to implement this then you need to change the layout param .

Hope this will work you