# how to use setX() and setY() method in android version less then 3.0

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to use android setX() and setY() method with version 2.1 but this is not applicable this method only applicable with android version greater then 3.0 please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10581797/1321873.

Answer (score 0):

@ Kirtika yes these method avaialble only version > 3.0 , but if you want to implement this need so you need to set layout param , i have implemented this thing .
put version check in your application if app found version is >3.0 then access the existing method other wise set param