# Increase size of the image view (android)

Tags: android

I have an imageview that loads and image in the xml.

I was wonder, how can I programmatically increase the image size ( or reduce it) by scale of 2? (so double it or make it half size)

Please help
Thanks

Comment: What kind of image is it? Bitmap? You can look into [`createScaledBitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: It is a drawable. As I said  I would like to call a method  or something on an ImageView

Comment: Ah, so like using `layoutParams`? [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965662/how-do-you-setlayoutparams-for-an-imageview). Then you can look into [`setScaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType%28android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType%29) to get the drawable to scale better