# Setting ImageView width and height before drawing in a ListView adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I have an adapter to a `ListView` is a list of `ImageView`s.  I am using a stretch to make the image fil the imageview so I can take smaller images and make them larger on the screen, however the `ImageView` normally just uses `wrap_content` and this is an issue because the images just show up as their normal width and height. Is there any way I can set the height and width of a view before drawing it because as in this case I do not have control over the view after it has been drawn. Here is my aapter method:

```
  @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String currentImage  = getItem(position);
    ScaleType scaleType = ScaleType.FIT_CENTER;
    float screenWidth = parent.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = new ImageView(parent.getContext()); 
    }
  //         WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO BE ABLE TO DO, but this returns null pointer exception
 //     convertView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) screenWidth;
//      convertView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) ((float)(screenWidth/currentImage.getWidth())*currentImage.getHeight());

    ((ImageView) convertView).setScaleType(scaleType);
    ((ImageView) convertView).setImageBitmap(MainActivity.cache.getBitmap(currentImage));
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Use setLayoutParams. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2965807/112381.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like `someView.setHeight() and someView.setWidth()`? Or `someView.setLayoutParams()`? You could add either of these to the overridden `getView()` callback and it should take care of your problem.

You could also [Create a Custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) and override something like getMeasuredWidthAndState(). (I think that's one of the right methods, but I'm not one hundred percent sure.) You could create a `width` class variable and a `height` class variable that all instances of your custom ImageView would use. However, that might be a bit much if you just want to set the layout width and height though.