# Adjust the Size of an ImageView

Tags: android, size, imageview

How do i adjust the Size and Position of an ImageView?

my code:

```
int id = R.drawable.x;
X = new ImageView(this);
X.setImageResource(id);
screen.addView(X);
```

Comment: If you want to set it in code, you can use [this thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2965807/876603

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
MarginLayoutParams params = new MarginLayoutParams(width, height);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
screen.addView(imageView);
```

width : provide the width you wanted

height : height of the view

left,top,right,bottom : to set the x,y position set the left margin and top margin.

You can also set the image scaleType.
For more info on ScaleType [see the developer doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
X = new ImageView(this);
X.setImageResource(R.drawable.x;);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
X.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
screen.addView(X);
```