# Setting layout_marginTop on ImageView?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have Framelayout with  2 components

- Linear layout
- ImageView

I want to set `android:layout_marginTop="100dp"` to the `Imageview` (**programatically** )

Stackoverflow solutions says :

```
ImageView imgv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.redLine);
FrameLayout frameLayout= (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) frameLayout.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0);
imgv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

But I get Cast exception :

> ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be
>   cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams

**Question**

How can I set this :`android:layout_marginTop="100dp"` to the `Imageview` (programatically ) ?

Additional info :

[image]

Imports :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate  of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965662/how-do-you-setlayoutparams-for-an-imageview

Comment: @Gumbo same execption. my code involved frameLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly more educational answer to your own solution:

`LayoutParams` are always of the type of the container a `View` (or `ViewGroup`) is added to. They relate to the 'parent' of the view, if you like.

In your example:

- The `FrameLayout` is added to a `LinearLayout`, hence its layout params are of type `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.
- The `ImageView` is added to a `FrameLayout`, hence its layout params are of type `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`.

With this information you should be able to deduce what's going wrong.

Spoiler: you're making the common mistake of thinking that the layout params of the `FrameLayout` are of type `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`. However, as they relate to the layout's *parent*, they're actually of type `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. Hence the class cast exception.

Answer (score 0):

Got it  :

```
      FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      params.setMargins(200, 1, 1, 1);
      imgv.setLayoutParams(params);
```